# Return not showing up when called

Tags: python, return

I'm trying to get the user guess the number the computer is producing randomly. When passing the return function nothing shows up.

```
user = 0
result = ""
import random
print ("Welcome to Guess My Number Game")

def main():
    #user input
    computer = random.randint(1,100)
    print(computer)
    user=int(input("Guess the number:"))
    return (result)

def results(result):
    computer = random.randint(1,100)
    diff = 0
    diff = user - computer
    if diff < -10:
        result = ("Too Low")
    elif diff > 10:
        result = ("Too High")
    elif diff < 0:
        result = ("Getting warmer, but still low")
    elif diff > 0:
        result = ("Getting warmer, but still high")
    else:
        guesses = str(guesses)
        result = ('Good job, you guessed correctly in,',guesses,'guesses!')
```

Comment: are you trying to print `return (result)`? Can you clarify what you mean by "nothing shows up".

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems in your indentation however, if I can understand the logic correctly, you can do something similar to the below in order to keep user asking for a guess till getting a match;

```
import random

def results(val):
    guesses = 0
    while True:
        user = int(input("Guess the number: "))
        guesses = guesses + 1
        diff = user - computer
        if diff < -10:
            print("Too Low")
        elif diff > 10:
            print("Too High")
        elif diff < 0:
            print("Getting warmer, but still low")
        elif diff > 0:
            print("Getting warmer, but still high")
        else:
            print('Good job, you guessed correctly in {} guesses!'.format(guesses))
            break
    return guesses

def main():
    computer = random.randint(1, 100)
    number_of_guesses = results(computer)
```

---

```
>>> results()
Guess the number: 2
Too Low
Guess the number: 10
Too Low
Guess the number: 50
Too High
Guess the number: 40
Too High
Guess the number: 30
Getting warmer, but still high
Guess the number: 25
Getting warmer, but still low
Guess the number: 26
Getting warmer, but still low
Guess the number: 28
Getting warmer, but still low
Guess the number: 29
Good job, you guessed correctly in 9 guesses!
9
```

Comment: So, what happens to my main()?

Comment: Sorry! Another question. If I want to continue the game, using while loop, do I do it before or after the break?

Comment: @lastdancestop then you should probably put the code in `main()` in a `while` loop.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that you are trying to print the result variable from the results method

If my above statement is correct you have a misunderstanding about what `return` does. `return` is usually placed in a function to that will *return* some value. So you should make your code into this.

```
computer = random.randint(1,100)
print(computer) #if you print this guessing the number will be very easy
user=int(input("Guess the number:"))
print(results(computer, user))

def results(computer, user):
   results = ""
   # computer = random.randint(1,100) #you wont need this either
   diff = 0
   diff = user - computer
   if diff < -10:
      result = ("Too Low")
   elif diff > 10:
      result = ("Too High")
   elif diff < 0:
      result = ("Getting warmer, but still low")
   elif diff > 0:
      result = ("Getting warmer, but still high")
   else:
      guesses = str(guesses)
      result = ('Good job, you guessed correctly in,',guesses,'guesses!')
   return result
```